# Is there a concept of Order or Priority in NUnit?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I am using **NUnit 3.12.0** and **NUnit3TestAdapter 3.16.1**.

Have tried searching on the net but didn't get a clear answer whether we can run our test in particular order or priority using **NUnit** and **NUnit3TestAdapter**?

Let say I have 5 methods (Say A, B, C, D, and E) with tags [] and I want to run it in the Order/Priority of B, C, E, A and D.

Please suggest if we can use any specific tag to describe order or priority as we do it in testNG like

```
@Test(priority = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit supports an `OrderAttribute`, which you may use to loosely control the ordering of test methods within a class. For your example, you could write:

```
[Test, Order(4)]
public void A() { }

[Test, Order(1)]
public void B() { }

[Test, Order(2)]
public void C() { }

[Test, Order(5)]
public void D() { }

[Test, Order(3)]
public void E() { }
```

A couple of notes:

1. I wrote "loosely" above because the attribute controls the order in which tests are **started**. There is no dependency involved. That is, in the case of parallel execution, test E will not wait for tests B and C to complete before running. Of course, if you don't enable parallel execution, then it will **look like** E is depending on A and B, so you need to remember that's not the case or (in case you do have a need for true dependency) mark the class in which you use the Order attribute as NonParallelizable.
2. Any tests in the same class **without** the OrderAttribute are started after all the tests with the attribute.

See the NUnit docs for more info about the Order attribute.